# When I edit any cell, I need a function to run. I tried onEdit but it's not getting trigger the function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I edit any cell, I need a function to run. I tried onEdit but it's not getting trigger the function.

[image]

```
 function Updates() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!D171').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!FD4'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};



function onEdit(e){
  const range = e.spreadsheet.getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!A1:AA2000');
 Updates
}
```

Comment: You undid an accidental formatting of code as code. You should do that on purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you need further help, please show what  you have tried to fix your code i.e. review the execution logs, research about the error message... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

> NOTE: Please also indicate your **main goal** of your code as currently it is vague to understand fully what it does, given that you've mentioned that you add it as a **Macro** in your spreadsheet file.

There are wrong syntax inside of your **onEdit** function. Correcting your script's syntax will make it look like this:

***[UPDATED]***

```
function Updates() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!D171').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!FD4'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};

//[UPDATE] if you're running the onEdit function as a macro
function onEdit() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!A1:AA2000');
  Updates();
}
```

### Explanation

***[ISSUE 1]***

Looking at your code, your **onEdit** doesn't run successfully because you're using the wrong syntax with your `e` event object. Instead of using `e.spreadsheet` *(**spreadsheet** doesn't exist as an event object value)* you need to use `e.source`as per the official Google documentation for [`onEdit` event object values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

Triggering your actual **onEdit** script will also log an error on the Apps Script editor as seen here:

[image]

You may view [***Use the Apps Script execution log***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#use_the_apps_script_execution_log) docs on how you can view your log executions.

***[ISSUE 2]***

You're running your `Updates` function wrong inside of your `onEdit` function. You need it to have an `()` after it, otherwise, it will only return the function object instead of the actual `Updates` function result that you want to get.

> ***A JavaScript function is defined with the function keyword, followed by a name, followed by parentheses ()***.

Kindly review the [JavaScript Function Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp#:%7E:text=A%20JavaScript%20function%20is%20defined,name%2C%20followed%20by%20parentheses%20().) to learn more about the correct syntax in running JavaScript functions.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. But i'm still getting wrong. 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined onEdit @ macros.gs:7

Comment: Note: I put all the code into Extensions>Apps Script>macros.gs

Comment: I have updated my answer script. Please take a look. The **TypeError** you're getting is expected. It seems you are running `onEdit(e)` function in your macro. **Please** take note that you can't place a **simple trigger** function such as **onEdit** with an event object as there will be no passed data to it's event object when you run it with a custom keyboard shortcut. Thus, you are getting the type error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh1 = e.source.getSheetByName("Purpose Driven Mission");
  const sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName("All Links");
  sh1.getRange("D171").copyto(sh2.getRange("FD4",SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false))
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. But i'm still getting wrong. TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined onEdit @ macros.gs:2

Comment: Note: I put all the code into Extensions>Apps Script>macros.gs

Comment: You cannot call this type of function from the script editor or a menu unless you supply the event object

Comment: Just save it in the script editor and go to the appropriate page and begin editing.